Upload file not working with basic_auth using (HasAuthentication) driver.register((UsernameAndPassword.of("username", "password"))
When using basic_authentication
(HasAuthentication) driver.register((UsernameAndPassword.of("username", "password"))
the upload file using sendkeys to html input type=file cause 422 http error during file upload.
Using selenium 4.24.0, java openJdk20
To login to the application I need to programming login popup window.

I cannot use robot class as I need to run test in -headless mode, so I decided to use basic authorization like that:
 ((HasAuthentication) driver.register(predicateURI, UsernameAndPassword.of("username", "password"));
and authorization works in headless mode, but I have an issue with upload file doing by sendkeys to the html input type=file.
browseExcelFile.sendKeys(absolutePath);
The 422 http error is return during upload the file. When I only changed login method to use robot class, upload file is working correctly.
I'm suspecting that credentials are attached to the request with upload file, which cause that file is recognized as incorrect.
Any idea how can I change login or upload file to work in headless mode?

you should include more code and the markup of the form at the time you submit.  There may be a difference in the way the submit happens.
